# Creating NUMERIC array from JSONB data in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Postgres JSONB data which contains an ARRAY of type NUMERIC. I want to extract this ARRAY and store it in a variable of type NUMERIC[]. Here's is my JSONB object.

```
{
  "userIds": [
    101,102,103
  ],
  "userRole": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Administrator"
  }
}
```

How can I extract userIds from this JSONB object and store them in NUMERIC[] as I have to iterate on this NUMERIC[]?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to extract the ids with `jsonb_array_elements`, parse them to the right data type and aggregate them again in an array, e.g.:

```
SELECT array_agg(id) FROM (
  SELECT
    (jsonb_array_elements('{
      "userIds": [101,102,103],
      "userRole": {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Administrator"
     }
   }'::jsonb->'userIds')::numeric)) j(id);

   array_agg   
---------------
 {101,102,103}
(1 row)
```

If you want to iterate over these values as rows in your resultset, don't bother with the outer query:

```
SELECT
  jsonb_array_elements('{
    "userIds": [101,102,103],
    "userRole": {
   "id": "1",
   "name": "Administrator"
    }}'::jsonb->'userIds')::numeric;

 jsonb_array_elements 
----------------------
                  101
                  102
                  103
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Jim Jones : What's wrong in this statement? Nothing is printing on console.     FOREACH userId IN ARRAY(SELECT array_agg(id) FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(jsonb -> 'userIds') :: NUMERIC) j(id))
            LOOP
                RAISE NOTICE 'userId --> %', userId;                
            END LOOP;

Comment: is the jsonb a variable/parameter?

Comment: yes it is a variable say userRoleJsonb which contains   {
  "userIds": [
    101,102,103
  ],
  "userRole": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Administrator"
  }
}

Comment: @java_maestros does it help ? `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunc(jsonb)
RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' COST 100 VOLATILE AS $BODY$
DECLARE i record;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements($1->'userIds') j(id) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'output from space %', i.id;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;`

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm. I was using the wrong function. It's jsonb_array_elements.